# Leaving a wide ball and running byes?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is it in the rules to run byes on a wide ball which the batsman leaves? So if I leave a wide ball, can I then run byes off it if the keeper fumbles, or will the byes not count?

Answer (score 1):

They are explicitly *not* byes; quoting from [Law 23.1 "Byes"](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/bye-and-leg-bye):

> If the ball, delivered by the bowler, **not being a Wide**, passes the striker without touching his/her bat or person, any runs completed by the batters from that delivery, or a boundary allowance, shall be credited as Byes to the batting side.

(my emphasis) However, note that doesn't mean you can't run; [Law 22.5 "Ball not dead"](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/wide-ball) makes this very clear:

> The ball does not become dead on the call of Wide ball.

just that they will be counted as wides, not byes. This makes a difference only to the statistics for the bowler and the wicketkeeper, nobody else really cares.